# Operator << in abstract classes, c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class, stream-operators

If I have an abstract class, let's call it "Vertebrate", it has a field `std::string name;` and it has a  pure virtual method 
`virtual void print(std::ostream&) const noexcept = 0;` which will be overridden in child classes and called in `operator<<`.

I get how polymorphism works, and how to implement the `operator<<` in inherited classes.

What I don't get:

I don't get this: how to implement an `operator<<` in that abstract class, that uses the virtual print function. Why this code does not work? My abstract class needs to have `operator<<`.

```
virtual void print(std::ostream&) const noexcept = 0;
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & str, Member &obj)
{
    return obj.print(str);
}
```

That is the abstract class code.

Comment: `operator<<` used for stream output must be a standalone, non-member function. You keep saying "my class has `operator<<`" or "implement `operator<<` in some class" - what exactly do you mean by that? Anyway, a single non-member function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, Vertebrate& obj) { obj.print(str); return str; }` should work for all classes derived from `Vertebrate` - you don't need a separate one for each class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to return the result of `print` which is `void`, but `operator<<` should return `std::ostream`.

The following should work:

```
class Vertebrate
{
    // ...
    virtual void print(std::ostream&) const noexcept = 0;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Vertebrate& obj)
{
    obj.print(stream);
    return stream;
}
```